# How can this insertion sort routine be improved?

Tags: python, sorting, insertion-sort

This is my implementation of the insertion sort as described in that Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest book. The only difference is that I'm using an inner for loop instead of a while loop. I feel it is a bit clunky. How can I simplify this ?

```
def isort(list):
  if len(list) <= 1:
    return list

  # pick the next item for insertion from LEFT to RIGHT
  for j in range(1, len(list)):
    current = list[j]

    # invariant: [0:j-1] is sorted
    # range(0,j) returns everything up j-1
    # Pick the next item to compare from RIGHT TO LEFT

    ip = j-1
    inorder = False
    moved = False

    for i in reversed(range(0,j)):
      ip = i
      if list[i] > current:
        # move it to the right
        list[i+1] = list[i]
        moved = True
      else:
        inorder = True
        break;

    if moved:
      if inorder:
        list[ip+1] = current
      else:
        list[ip] = current

  return list
```

Comment: "How can I simplify this?"  Call `.sort()` on your list.

Comment: @robert the OP is obviously interested in understanding Insertion Sort Algorithm, not sorting a particular list.

Comment: I'm learning insertion sort & python. So this is an educational exercise.

Comment: @mjv: Please check your sarcasm filter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of iterating through `range(len(list)` do `for index, item in enumerate(list)`. In that case index will be your index and item will be the value of the item you're looking at.
2. Do the same for your nested for loop.

BTW, Franck Ribery is one of my favorite soccer players.

Comment: I'll try out your suggestions. Yes, Ribery rocks. Butt ugly but very talented.